# Termios syntax configuration with bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
newattr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO);
```

Here new values for `c_lflag` has been set. But I can't figure out what does this mean `&= ~` and what does `|` signify in between `ICANON` and `ECHO`?

Comment: This looks like a question about basic C syntax, not termios specific, you should tag it as such.

Comment: What source are you learning C from? Doesn't it have a list of operators you can check?

Comment: Google: "tilde operator", "and operator", "compound assignment operators". Or just "C operators", really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On macOS, the values for `ICANON` and `ECHO` are defined in `/usr/include/sys/termios.h` as:

```
#define ECHO    0x00000008  /* enable echoing */
#define ICANON  0x00000100  /* canonicalize input lines */
```

The values may be different on your machine; the details don't matter much, but the crucial point that each is a number with a single bit set.

The `|` operator forms the bitwise 'or' of the two numbers: `0x000000108`.

The `~` operator forms the bitwise complement of the two numbers: `0xFFFFFEF7`.

The `&=` takes the value already in `newattr.c_lflag` and forms the bitwise 'and' with the value `0xFFFFFEF7`.  This has the net result of preserving every bit already set in the variable except the `ECHO` and `ICANON` bits, which are both set to `0`.

The notation `value & ~(bit1 | bit2 …)` is a standard C idiom for clearing bits that might or might not be set in an integer.  The corresponding setting code is `value | (bit1 | bit2 …)`, where the parentheses are optional since the operator is the same throughout.  You use bitwise 'xor' or `^` to flip bits — to change `1` into `0` or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

It is bit twiddling. The `ICANON` and `ECHO` flags are being cleared in the `c_lflag` field of the `termios` structure.

This is very, very basic C syntax. You should take the time to review the C bit operators.